# Depreciation Calculator modifications

Tags: vb.net

As the title suggest, I need help on changing the code on an old project I'm planning on revamping for an upcoming one. I need to change the Financial.DDB to Financial.SLN without an error occuring concerning there being too many arguments. Also I think the Main_Form_Load contents should be replaced with lstUsefulLife.Items.Add("2") to ("20"). Can anyone help? Here's the code.

Public Class Main_Form

```
Private Sub Main_Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    Do
        lstUsefulLife.Items.Add(i.ToString())
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i <= 20

End Sub

Private Sub btnSchedule_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSchedule.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim amount As Double
    txtSchedule.Text = ""
    txtSchedule.Text = "Year" & vbTab & "Depreciation" & vbNewLine
    Dim years As Integer
    years = Convert.ToDouble(lstUsefulLife.SelectedItem)

    i = 1
    Do
        amount = Financial.DDB(Convert.ToDouble(txtAsset.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtSalvage.Text), years, i)
        txtSchedule.Text = txtSchedule.Text & i & vbTab & amount.ToString("N2") & vbNewLine
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i <= years
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    End
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I'd start by looking at the documentation for Financial.DDB and Financial.SLN.  The first one takes 3 required arguments, with the last 2 optional, one of which, the period, you've provided.  The second one only takes 3 required arguments, without having the option for additional ones (as it is only used for 1 period).  You need to remove "i" from the function call.

Comment: However, if you're looking for someone to figure out how to change your code from one financial method to another and code it for you, you are in the wrong place.  People are glad to help with specific programming questions, but this is not a code factory.  You need to at least describe exactly what you want to happen from your code, including the input and output, and the things you have tried to make this happen and the specific issue you are having in causing the desired output and I'm sure someone will gladly help.

Comment: No much clear .. what change you asking for.. try to edit your question and add more information on it